# php unserialize data from table not working

Tags: php, serialization

i need to unserialize a string to an array.Here is the stringwhich needs to be unserialized in php to assosiative array.

```
a:1:{i:0;s:158:"a:6:{s:5:"rowid";s:32:"94ca9ee0c4e3184b50e89e82f80332fb";s:2:"id";
s:2:"68";s:3:"qty";s:1:"1";s:5:"price";
s:2:"20";s:4:"name";
s:5:"Bread";s:8:"subtotal";i:20;}";
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this has been doubly serialized. It expands to an array with a single element, and that element is a serialized associative array. So you need to do:

```
$temp = unserialize($data);
$result = unserialize($temp[0]);
var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
array(6) {
  ["rowid"]=>
  string(32) "94ca9ee0c4e3184b50e89e82f80332fb"
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "68"
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["price"]=>
  string(2) "20"
  ["name"]=>
  string(5) "Bread"
  ["subtotal"]=>
  int(20)
}
```

If there can be more that one element in the top-level serialized array, use `array_map` to unserialize all of them:

```
$result = array_map('unserialize', $temp);
```

`$result` will now be a 2-dimensional array.

I'm not sure why you stored your data this way. Why not just serialize the original 2-d array all at once, instead of nesting them?

Comment: its working fine, but how could we foreach this array to get the values

Comment: thanx it worked fine, the string is returned from an api call.