# How do I access values in a string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a module (not mine) that returns an ID I must use in my php app. But the returned ID is in this weird format I don't understand. It contains pairs of key/values:

Here is an example of the returned string:

```
a:10:{s:2:"id";s:24:"5b066f2f0cf2e7cb2e8ba33a";s:3:"value";s:25:"testing";}
```

How would I parse this in PHP and access the keys and values (in this instance "id" and "value")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php unserialize data from table not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569716/php-unserialize-data-from-table-not-working). Couldnt find a better match. At least it shows the code needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [serialized](http://php.net/serialize) array.  You can convert it back to an array with [unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize).

```
$arr = unserialize($str);
```